# Solving simultaneous equations involving a quadratic

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the question

Solve the simultaneous equation  pair

$$x^2 + y^2 = 25\tag1$$
$$2x - y = 5\tag2$$

---

I have found the value of $y$ from the second equation which is $2x-5$ and substituted this into the first equations $y$ value.

I get $x^2 + (2x -5)^2 = 25$

When I expand the brackets I get the equation 
$$x^2+4x^2-20 =0\tag3$$

However, when I checked the solutions the equation should simplify to $x^2 - 4x = 0$ and I do not understand how this is achieved.

Comment: If I had to guess, you're not expanding $(2x-5)^2$ correctly.  Could you include your expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2 + y^2 = 25 $$

$$2x - y = 5 \Leftrightarrow y=2x-5$$

$$ x^2 + (2x-5)^2 = 25 $$

$$ x^2 +4x^2 -20x +25 = 25 $$

$$ 5x^2 -20x=0 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + (2x-5)^2 = x^2 + (2x)^2 - 2\cdot (2x)\cdot 5 + 5^2$$

What do you get when you simplify this further?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{x}^2+\text{y}^2=25\\
2\text{x}-\text{y}=5
\end{cases}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space
\begin{cases}
\text{x}^2+\left(2\text{x}-5\right)^2=25\\
\text{y}=2\text{x}-5
\end{cases}
$$

Solving:

$$\text{x}^2+\left(2\text{x}-5\right)^2=25$$

Gives us $x=0$ or $x=4$

Comment: How is X^2 - 4X = 0 achieved from this ?

Comment: @Dan notice that $\left(2x-5\right)^2=4x^2-20x+25$